# Inverse matrix inequality $\|A^{-1}v\|_2 \ge \|A^{-1}\|_2|u^Tv|$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix of size $n \times n$.
Let $v$ be an arbitrary unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e., $\|v\|_2=1$.
Then there exists a unit vector $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$\|A^{-1}u\|_2 = \|A^{-1}\|_2$.

I am trying to show the following inequality
$$ \|A^{-1}v\|_2 \ge \|A^{-1}\|_2|u^Tv|. $$

Here is my try.

We can write
$$ v = (u^Tv)u + (v-(u^Tv)u). $$
Thus 
$$ A^{-1}v = (u^Tv)A^{-1}u + A^{-1}(v-(u^Tv)u).$$
If somehow the first and the second terms in the RHS are orthogonal, 
I can write
$$  (*) \quad \|A^{-1}v\|_2^2 = \|(u^Tv)A^{-1}u \|_2^2 + \|A^{-1}(v-(u^Tv)u\|_2^2
\ge \|(u^Tv)A^{-1}u \|_2^2 $$
which gives the desired inequality
$$ \|A^{-1}v\|_2 \ge \|(u^Tv)A^{-1}u \|_2 = |u^Tv|\|A^{-1}u\|_2 = |u^Tv|\|A^{-1}\|_2.$$
However, (*) is not true in general.
So I am stucked on here.

Any comments or suggestions will be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a change of (orthonormal) basis, we may assume that $A^{-1}=Q\Sigma$ is a singular value decomposition, where $Q$ is real orthogonal, $\Sigma=\operatorname{diag}(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n)$ is the singular value matrix and $u=e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$. Then the inequality in question reduces to $\|\Sigma v\|_2\ge\sigma_1|e_1^Tv|$, which is trivial.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!